# Filter a list of dictionaries by nested id from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to filer a list of dictionaries (`includes`) by nested `id` from another dictionary (`relationships`).

Below is the test data:

```
relationships = {
    'author': {
        'data': {
            'type': 'users',
            'id': '22DB1A00-0000-0000-00009BC6',
        }
    },
    'parent': {
        'data': {
            'type': 'documents',
            'id': 'BE7F4800-0000-0000-000021F6',
        }
    },
    'pages_file': {
        'data': None
    },
    'fields': {
        'data': [
            {
                'type': 'dictionary',
                'id': 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0001',
            },
            {
                'type': 'dictionary',
                'id': 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0002',
            },
        ]
    },
}

includes = [
    {'type': 'users', 'id': '22DB1A00-0000-0000-00009BC6'},
    {'type': 'dictionary', 'id': 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0002'},
    {'type': 'dictionary', 'id': 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0003'},
]
```

The result I need should looks as follows:

```
[{'type': 'users', 'id': '22DB1A00-0000-0000-00009BC6'},
 {'type': 'dictionary', 'id': 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0002'}]
```

To clarify: The new dictionary I want to get after filtering should have the same `id` and `type` as nested dicts from `relationships`.

Comment: Just to understand, you are trying to get a new list from a list of dics, and in that new list you only want to include the dics that have a cartain value when it comes to the ```[id]``` attribute, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The new dictionary I want to get after filtering should have the same `id` and `type` as nested dicts from `relationships`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
def filter_includes(relationships, includes):
    def normalize(data):
        if data is None:
            return []
        return data if isinstance(data, list) else [data]

    def simplify(r):
        return ((d['type'], d['id']) for i in r for d in normalize(r[i]['data']))

    r_set = set(simplify(relationships))

    return [e for e in includes if (e['type'], e['id']) in r_set]
```

The test:

```
def test_filter_includes():
    result = filter_includes(relationships, includes)
    assert len(result) == 2
    assert result[0]['id'] == '22DB1A00-0000-0000-00009BC6'
    assert result[1]['id'] == 'B15E5D00-0000-0000-000021F6-0002'

    result = filter_includes({}, includes)
    assert len(result) == 0

    includes[0]['type'] = 'content_file'
    includes[1]['type'] = 'content_file'
    includes[2]['type'] = 'content_file'

    result = filter_includes(relationships, includes)
    assert len(result) == 0

    includes[0]['type'] = 'documents'
    includes[0]['id'] = 'BE7F4800-0000-0000-000021F6'

    result = filter_includes(relationships, includes)
    assert len(result) == 1
    assert result[0]['type'] == 'documents'
    assert result[0]['id'] == 'BE7F4800-0000-0000-000021F6'
```